# How do i reverse the element of this array using lambda

Tags: ruby, lambda

How do i reverse the element of this array using lambda ..

```
array = ["Hello","World"]
```

How do i reverse the elements in the array so that it is like this:

```
array = ["olleH","dlroW"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array.map(&:reverse)
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why would you use lambda for this but who am I to judge :)

```
lambda{|a| a.map(&:reverse)}.call(["Hello","World"].reverse)
```